# How do you say 'This took a dark turn.' in German?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

How do you say "This took a dark turn / This turned dark real quick/fast"?

Dictionaries offer "dunkel, finster, düster, freudlos", but I don't think these reflect the emotion behind the sentence.

Comment: Please imagegoogle *düster*.

Comment: Please add more context. Expressions can never be translated correctly without concrete context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of these adjectives describe it perfectly. I was surprised not to find this phrase in common dictionaries.

> Das nahm eine düstere Wendung
>
> Der Film ist plötzlich ziemlich düster geworden.
> Die Geschichte nahm ohne Vorwarnung einen düsteren Verlauf.

Comment: Thank you! Having never heard of this word, I didn't think it would be suitable.